# Software to OCR documents with columns in two languages plus images

Tags: ocr

We have a series of documents with a Wakashan (an aboriginal British Columbia) language in the left column, and its English translation in the right, and artist's drawings interspersed with the texts.

Is there some software, preferably free, that would enable us to convert the texts to Unicode texts? (We do not want to make any translations.)